# How to split a List of Strings in Java with a regex that uses the last occurrence of given Pattern?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm pretty new to the regex world.
Given a list of Strings as input, I would like to split them by using a regex of punctuations pattern: `"[!.?\n]"`.

The thing is, I would like to specify that if there are multiple punctuations together like this:

input: `"I want it now!!!"`

output: `"I want it now!!"`

input: `"Am I ok? Yeah, I'm fine!!!"`

output: [`"Am I ok"`, `"Yeah, I'm fine!!"`]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
[!.?\n](?![!.?\n])
```

Here, a `!`, `.`, `?` or newline are matched only if not followed with any of these chars.

Or, if the char must be repeated:

```java
([!.?\n])(?!\1)
```

Here, a `!`, `.`, `?` or newline are matched only if not followed with exactly the same char.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/5ZjYq1/2) and the [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/5ZjYq1/1/).

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/7g3fiy):

```java
String p = "[!.?\n](?![!.?\n])";
String p2 = "([!.?\n])(?!\\1)";
String s = "I want it now!!!";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(p)));  // => [I want it now!!]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(p2))); // => [I want it now!!]
s = "Am I ok? Yeah, I'm fine!!!";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(p)));  // => [Am I ok,  Yeah, I'm fine!!]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(p2))); // => [Am I ok,  Yeah, I'm fine!!]
```

Answer (score 0):

The split() methos of String accept as delimitator a regular expression.

Ref.: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Example:

```
String str = "Am I ok? Yeah, I'm fine!!!";
String delimiters = "[!.?\n]";

String[] splitted = str.split(delimiters);
    
for(String part : splitted) {
   System.out.print(part + "\n");
}
```

Output:

> Am I ok
>
> Yeah, I'm fine